# Jquery each on a specific form elements only

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to make my own form validator

At first I was using this code

```
    $(".check_submit").submit(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();

            var error = false;

            $(".req_field").each(function( index ){

                    if(!$(this).val()){                
                        error = true;
                    }                                    

            });

            if(error == false){
                this.submit();                    
            }else{
                alert("fill all please");
            }                

    });
```

then i found that if i have more than one form in the same page conflicts happen,

So I wrote this code but there is some thing wrong

```
    $(".check_submit").submit(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();

            var error = false;

            $(this).children(".req_field").each(function( index ){

                    if(!$(this).val()){                
                        error = true;
                    }                                    

            });

            if(error == false){
                this.submit();                    
            }else{
                alert("fill all please");
            }                

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `find()` instead:

```
$(this).find(".req_field").each(...)
```

`children()` will look only for first level descendants

Answer (score 2):

You need "find" instead of "children".
"Children" only selects the immediate descendants.